# Is there a way to prevent excel showing the drop down button, in a data validation cell?

Tags: excel

Is it possible for excel to prevent the drop down toggle on a cell which has data validation? I am wanting the data validation to apply, but i would prefer the drop down button to not appear.

The reason for this, is the user is not having to choose a value, instead they handheld scan their ID badge.

I have searched everywhere and cannot find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Untick the box "in-Cell Dropdown" in the data validation for that cell. - Also you should remove the VBA and Excel-VBA tags as it has nothing to do with VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to uncheck the `In-Cell Drop-down` checkbox.

[image]